# How to configure wiremock to send different responses (same url and requests) after reaching previous count of request?

Tags: wiremock

It is possible to configure wiremock to send different responses on same URL and same request after particular count of previous responses?

```
For example: 
1st request -> 503 response
2nd request -> 503 response
3rd request -> 503 response
4th request -> 200 response
```

This would simulate unavailable service during startup. And when it is up and running, then it responds 200 status.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this using WireMock's [Scenario feature.](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) A potential set-up could be something like...

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/foo")).inScenario("Test Scenario")
    .whenScenarioStateIs(STARTED)
    .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(503))
    .willSetStateTo("One Attempt"));
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/foo")).inScenario("Test Scenario")
    .whenScenarioStateIs("One Attempt")
    .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(503))
    .willSetStateTo("Two Attempts"));
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/foo")).inScenario("Test Scenario")
    .whenScenarioStateIs("Two Attempts")
    .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)));
```

In the above, you are setting up the Scenario by defining the scenario name and the initial behavior (all Scenarios begin in a state of `STARTED`.) After the first time running into the `"/foo"` endpoint, we return a 503 status, and the state of the Scenario is changed to "One Attempt". After the second time running into the `"/foo"` endpoint, we return a 503 status again, and the state of the Scenario is changed to "Two Attempts". If we hit the `"/foo"` endpoint again, we will return a 200 status, and not change the Scenario state.

One caveat is that you'll need to know the exact amount of times you'd like to return a specific status, so it won't allow you to return a 503 at random. But if you are certain you'll always need a specific amount of responses before just returning a 200, then scenarios should work.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about scenarios in wiremock. I was wondering if there is configuration like you define number of requests instead of specifying each request. But your answer helped me a lot.